# How can I get the description error from stripe?

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe in my app. The code works but I would like to get the description error and show it to user with a label in case something goes wrong (CC number not correct etc):

```
      // other stuff here


     STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(stripeCard) { (token, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error  {

            print(error.userInfo)
        }
        else if let token = token {
            self.createBackendChargeWithToken(token) { status in
                if status == PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success{

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                        self.paymentActivity.hidden = true
                        self.paymentActivity.stopAnimating()
                        self.paymentActivityLabel.text = "Transaction approved!"

                    }



                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

when I print `error.userInfo` I get the following:

```
[com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey: Your card number is incorrect.,
com.stripe.lib:CardErrorCodeKey: com.stripe.lib:IncorrectNumber,
com.stripe.lib:ErrorParameterKey: number, 
NSLocalizedDescription: Your card's number is invalid]
```

How can I extrapolate `NSLocalizedDescription`?

Comment: Does `print(error.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"])` work? Not sure given your snippet if the keys are strings or not.

Comment: I tried that but it returns `nil`

Comment: Ok. We need to know what's in this object. First, you can do ALT+CLICK on "userInfo", Xcode will show you the type. Maybe there's a type specific to Stripe in there. If it's not enough, we'll use a breakpoint.

Comment: thanks. it's `var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] { get }`

Comment: @EricD. apologies... I though I had tried that. IT WORKS! I will accept the answer if you post it. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `error.userInfo` is usually an NSDictionary.

When you print this dictionary, there's no types like with a Swift dictionary, so the print function does not always recognize what are strings, and does not show double quotes. But your `userInfo` dictionary keys are still probably strings.

I would first try accessing the error value like this:

```
print(error.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"])
```

to verify that indeed `NSLocalizedDescription` is a string key.

*A tip: hold ALT and CLICK on a variable, it will show you its type, it helps for quickly debugging in Xcode.*